# Update Table Nested Query (Using Function)

Tags: mysql

in my query i want to update row of table "tblUser_Report". it has date field i want to update only row which has highest date value (I mean most recent date )

But i m getting error that u cant include "from" in "update"...any other way to do it ?
P.S. Database :- MySQL

```
update tblUser_Report set Status='A',S_Date='"+date+"' 
    where Employee_ID="+id+" 
    AND 
    S_Date=(select MAX(S_Date) 
    from tblUser_Report 
    where Employee_ID="+id+")";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query, with a JOINed subquery -

```
UPDATE tblUser_Report t1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(S_Date) s_date
      FROM
        tblUser_Report
      WHERE
        Employee_ID = 1) t2
ON t1.s_date = t2.s_date
SET
  t1.Status = 'A', t1.S_Date = DATE(NOW())
WHERE
  t1.Employee_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, the `tblUser` has a primary key, then:

```
UPDATE tblUser t
JOIN (
  SELECT the_pk
  FROM tblUser
  WHERE Employee_ID=@employee_id
  ORDER BY S_Date DESC
  LIMIT 1) s
USING (the_pk)
SET Status = 'A', S_Date = @new_date;
```

Comment: tblUser_Report does not have primary key.thats why it has multiple entries for Employee ID ..i am selecting row who's date field is most recent.

Comment: @sagar-dumbre, then I would rewrite the query almost equally to the Devart's solution. By why not to add an identity field?

Comment: The above table Generate report so it doesnt have a primary key.One Emp ID can have many entries.select entry with recent date